# Jboss GC settings

Tags: jboss, garbage-collection

We are using jboss EAP-6.4.0/jboss

i am trying to enforce GC every 30 mins. the start up file is as below

```
 NO_GC_LOG_ROTATE=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-verbose:gc"`
if [ "x$NO_GC_LOG_ROTATE" = "x" ]; then
    # backup prior gc logs
    mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.0" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.0" >/dev/null 2>&1
    mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.1" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.1" >/dev/null 2>&1
    mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.2" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.2" >/dev/null 2>&1
    mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.3" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.3" >/dev/null 2>&1
    mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log.4" "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.4" >/dev/null 2>&1
    mv "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR"/gc.log.*.current "$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/backupgc.log.current" >/dev/null 2>&1
    "$JAVA" $JVM_OPTVERSION -verbose:gc -Xloggc:"$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:+UseParallelOldGC **-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=1800000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=1800000** -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading -version >/dev/null 2>&1 && mkdir -p $JBOSS_LOG_DIR && PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS="$PREPEND_JAVA_OPTS -verbose:gc -Xloggc:\"$JBOSS_LOG_DIR/gc.log\" -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=3M -XX:-TraceClassUnloading"
fi
```

Not sure why this isn't working???

Answer (score 1):

GC logs in EAP cannot rotate on a time based rotation. Rather, they can rotate on a size based rotation.

The gc.log can be rolled through JVM settings UseGCLogFileRotation / NumberOfGCLogFiles / GCLogFileSize on the OpenJDK  Oracle JDK. For example:

```
-verbose:gc -Xloggc:gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=1048576
```

Comment: Thanks Viral , this helped me pretty good  
I am not looking to rotate the GC logs, but want GC to happen every 1 hour

Comment: As i commented to you previously, you can only rotate the GC logs based on file size. GC log file cannot rotate on time based rotation.